# Web site analytic application in the mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

I would like to integrate the web site analytic into my web application

Till now as far as my knowledge and study

Could you please explain how to integrate website analytic in my application. How to do this.

Comment: There are several tutorials in the Google Analytics documentation. Is there anything specifically you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

There is and API for Google Analytics, which you can use to get analytics data from Google. Check out this - http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/

You can check this tutorial - [Google Analytics Data Export API with Asp.Net MVC](http://www.nickkipling.com/blog/google-analytics-data-export-api-with-asp-net-mvc)